# Error 1133 when creating users in SQL script?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this .sql script I've written which, among other things, creates the DB, creates tables, creates procedures, and sets up users.

Here is a segment of it:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'fwtrRWW';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'fwtrRW';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'fwtrR';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE USER 'fwtrRWW'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123';
CREATE USER  'fwtrRW'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc213';
CREATE USER  ' fwtrR'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

GRANT ALL                    ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrRWW';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrRW';
GRANT SELECT                 ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrR';
```

I keep getting MySQL error *1133: Can't find any matching row in the user table*, despite the fact that `SELECT * FROM mysql.User` clearly shows that the users are there.

I have tried putting more `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` in here and there but it doesn't seem to help like it does for others on other forums.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Add @'localhost' to the usernames in your grant statement?

Comment: Try `DROP USER` instead of accessing the users table directly: `DROP USER 'fwtrRWW'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change your `GRANT` statements to:

```
GRANT ALL                    ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrRWW'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrRW'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT                 ON fwtr.* TO 'fwtrR'@'localhost';
```